# create round image and a detailed box beside it css, html, bootsrap

Tags: html, css, image

how can i achieve the attached layout 
using html, bootstrap, CSS 
 where the circles will contains an images
and a detail box will be beside them

question has been updated with code snippet 
what i have done is not accurate the sizes not responsive

and if i make the circle bigger than the rectangle it does not align vertically in middle
also the code inside the rectangle is not middle 
could any one please provide me a demo 
[custom layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs1Qj.png)

```css
   .rectangle1{
        display:block;
        height:40px;
        width:150px;
        background:red;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:100px;
      }

      .circle1{
        position:absolute;
        height:40px;
        width:40px;
        border-radius:40px;
        border:3px solid white;
        left:0%;
        margin-left:-25px;
        top: 0px;
        background:red;
      }
      .rectangle1{
       display: inline-block;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100%;
       background: #6f0a18;
       position: relative;
     }

     .circle1{
      position:absolute;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      border-radius:50%;
      border:3px solid white;
      left:0%;
      margin-left:-25px;
      top: 0px;
      background:red;
    }


    .circle2{
      position:absolute;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      border-radius:50%;
      border:3px solid white;
      right:0%;
      margin-right:-25px;
      top: 0px;
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="rectangle1">
        <img class="circle1" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/camera-icon-circle-21.png"  />
        <h3 style="padding-left: 100px;">Title</h3>
        <p style="padding-left: 100px;"> Sub Title</p>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="rectangle1">
       <img class="circle2" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/camera-icon-circle-21.png"  />
       <h3 style="padding-right: 100px; text-align: right;">Title</h3>
       <p style="padding-right: 100px; text-align: right;"> Sub Title</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please let us know if you tried or researched something.  A code snippet will help understand your approach.

Comment: What you are asking is pretty basic so it seems you need to go over the basics first. After that, try to implement it yourself and if you don't succeed, show us what you tried and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .outer-wrapp {
      padding:30px;
    }
    ul {
      list-style:none;
      padding:0;
    }
    ul li {
          margin: 55px 0px;
    }
    .wrapp{
      padding:0px 15px;
    }
    .left .box {
      position:relative;
      width:95%;
      height:35px;
      border:1px solid #000;
      margin-left: 5%;
      padding-left: 20%;
    }
    .left .circle {
      position:absolute;
      width:75px;
      height:75px;
      border-radius:50%;
      background:#000;
      top: calc(50% - 37.5px);
      left: -37.5px;
    }
    
    .right .box {
      position:relative;
      width:95%;
      height:35px;
      border:1px solid #000;
      margin-right: 5%;
      padding-right: 20%;
    }
    .right .circle {
      position:absolute;
      width:75px;
      height:75px;
      border-radius:50%;
      background:#000;
      top: calc(50% - 37.5px);
      right: -37.5px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <div class="outer-wrapp">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
          <ul class="left">
            <li>
              <div class="wrapp">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                  <span>Text</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="wrapp">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="wrapp">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
          <ul class="right">
            <li>
              <div class="wrapp">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="wrapp">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="wrapp">
                <div class="box">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Try this. it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.circle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#id1 {
   
    
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 11px;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    
   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Circle CSS</h2>
<div class="circle"><div id='id1'>  text here</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.container{
width:100%;
background:red;
margin:10px 0;
}

#image{
width:20%;
float:left;
}


#image img{
border-radius: 50px;
}

#text{
width:80%;
float:left;
}

#text h3{
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
<div id='image'>
<img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000017423279/1a6d6f295da9f97bb576ff486ed81389_400x400.png' width='100%' />
</div>

<div id="text">
<h3> Hello </h3>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
<div id='image'>
<img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000017423279/1a6d6f295da9f97bb576ff486ed81389_400x400.png' width='100%' />
</div>

<div id="text">
<h3> Hello </h3>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```